# How to send dates to read-only calendar input boxes using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to specify the beg and end dates.

[image]

I can't change the default dates, because the input boxes are read only. Or, I have to select the dates from clicking the calendar. Don't know how to do that.  Is there a way to send keys to read-only input boxes?

The sources of the two input boxes are as follows:

```
       <div class="date-from">
                <h3>From</h3>
                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Jan 11, 2020">
                <button class="icon la-Calendar"></button>
            </div>

      <div class="date-to">
                        <h3>To</h3>
                        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Jan 11, 2020">
                        <button class="icon la-Calendar"></button>
                    </div>
```

My following code gets the "Message: invalid element state" error. Thank you!

```
      browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bpcg9kk"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input').clear()
      browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bpcg9kk"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input').send_keys("Jan 01,2019")
```

[Update] Almost there. Using the following code. The beg-date is changed successfully. The end-date has an issue. The beg-date also ends up in the end-date box.

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bpcg9kk"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')",element)
element.clear()
element.send_keys("Jan 01, 2019")
time.sleep(5)

element2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bpcg9kk"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/input')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')",element2)
element2.clear()
element2.send_keys("Dec 31, 2019")
```

[image]

Comment: Problem with clearing the field. If you are not able to clear with clear(). You can try it with Action class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below lines instead `send_keys` to write date in date input field. Basically we directly changing value of element.

```
element= browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bpcg9kk"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input')

    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', ‘“Jan 01,2019"')", element);

    OR



    browser.execute_script(“arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", element, “Jan 01,2019”)
```

**Another solution:**

Make input field as editable by removing `readonly` attribute and then send keys as below

```
element= browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bpcg9kk"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input')


browser.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')",element)

element.send_keys("Jan 01,2019")
```

**Clear field:**

```
element2.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
 element2.send_keys(Keys.DELETE);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm able to change the dates on the web page using your code. However, it seems that the new dates are not sent to the server, because the search results returned are still based on the default dates. Is there anything else I needs to do? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check the code under Another solution

Comment: Almost there. The second input box for the end date is not changed successfully. Please see update in my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, what's that?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I have updated answer with clear field solution. Please check.

Comment: Please check and let me know.